# Is it impossible to evaluate the generator distribution directly?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, generator

The following excerpt is taken from `3. The Inception Score for Image Generation` from the paper titled [A Note on the Inception Score.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.01973.pdf)

> Suppose we are trying to evaluate a trained generative model $G$ that
> encodes a distribution $p_g$ over images $\hat{x}$. We can sample from
> $p_g$ as many times as we would like, **but do not assume that we can
> directly evaluate $p_g$**. The Inception Score is one way to evaluate
> such a model.

The excerpt is saying that we are not directly evaluating the $p_g$, the generator distribution but trying to evaluate the model $G$.

Does the excerpt intend to say that it is practically impossible to evaluate $p_g$?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the excerpt intend to say that it is practically impossible to evaluate $p_g$?

No, this statement says that they *assume* that they are not going to directly evaluate $p_g$ for a given problem, and offer other evaluation criteria which does not require doing so, which is the point of the paper. I think the authors have chosen the wording carefully and accurately.

They have probably been motivated to publish about this approach, because it is not possible to evaluate $p_g$ in most use cases for GANs. Image generators output highly complex functions with very high dimensionality and a lot of correlation between pixel values. So the paper is of interest *because* it is hard (usually a practical impossibility) to define $p_g$ directly, or use something like [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) to assess the generator's match to the real distribution.